# PayU Money with web view stopped working suddenly

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, payment-gateway, payumoney

I have integrated PayUMoney gateway with UIWebView in one of my application. It was working fine in both the test and live environment. Now when I am testing it again in test environment, with "Debit card" option, it is not working. Although it is working as expected when I am choosing COD option.
Screen shot of related error is attached here -
[image]

Comment: I think you need to contact to PayU money support team,Beacuse error is not in your code.

Comment: can u post some error?

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. It was a stupid issue until now I was able to test the payment with any expiry date of card, but today it was not working. Solution was to test it with expiry date provided by them 05/2020  :)